# PHPDoc @return type equals class field type (in PhpStorm 10.0.4)

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, phpdoc

So I have a *trait* like as below:

```
trait RepositoryTrait
{
    /**
     * Find a model by its primary key.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param array $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function find($id, array $columns = ['*'])
    {
        return $this->query()->find($id, $columns);
    }
}
```

and the interface:

```
interface Repository
{
    /**
     * Find a model by its primary key.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param array $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function find($id, array $columns = ['*']);
}
```

and I have repository class like:

```
class FixedAssetRepository implements Repository
{
    use RepositoryTrait;

    /**
     * FixedAsset model.
     *
     * @var FixedAsset
     */
    protected $model;

    /**
     * Repository constructor.
     *
     * @param FixedAsset $fixedAsset
     */
    public function __construct(FixedAsset $fixedAsset)
    {
        $this->model = $fixedAsset;
    }
}
```

and what I'm looking for is to define somehow that method `find` (in trait or interface) is type of `FixedAsset` - but this should work always for each new `Repository` class that I'll create (that implements Repository interface).

I need it for type hinting in **PhpStorm 10.0.4**

Is it possible somehow?

So the result should be that when I call somewhere I.e.:

```
$fixedAsset = $this->fixedAssetRepositry->find($id);
```

PhpStorm will know that `$fixedAsset` is a object of a class `FixedAsset` not just `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` (now is working like that).

So I need something that like in interface (or trait?):

```
   /**
     * Find a model by its primary key.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param array $columns
     * @return $this->model
     */
    public function find($id, array $columns = ['*']);
```

but of course `@return $this->model` doesn't work.

I'll be appreciated for any suggestions about that.

Comment: The best **I** could think of right now is to use `@method` and "redeclare" it with correct return type -- see if this will work.

Comment: Great! How simple... That's what I need. Thank you very much. You can post this answer that I could mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I can think of right now would be using `@method` in PHPDoc comment for that `FixedAssetRepository` class and "redeclare" that `find()` method with correct signature (return type). Since it's a PHPDoc solution it will not have any effect on PHP code during runtime.

Sample code:

```
/**
 * @method FixedAsset find(int $id, array $columns) Find a model by its primary key
 */
class FixedAssetRepository implements Repository
{
...
```

More on the `@method` tag -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#711-method